# How to correctly float an image to the left when placed in a sequence of divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a sequence of divs in html.

Each div has an image that I want to take up on the left. Each div will also have a set of information of varying length that I want to display to the right of that image.

The problem I'm having is that the images being floated to the left are catching on each other. What I want is for each .item div to display in sequence down the page, but instead they crawl slowly to the right as each image catches on itself.

Note that in the real-world example this is based on, the heights of the images and the number of the lines in the details section may vary, so it is not known ahead of time which of the two will be longer than the other for any given .item div.

I'm sure I used to know how to do this, but for the life of me I can't work it out. I'm either stupid or merely in very bad need of caffeine. It's clearly been far too long since I dabbled in web design.

Sample code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Float Left Sample</title>
<style>
    .sidebar { 
        float: left; 
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Sample Image" />
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div>Details Line One</div>
                <div>Details Line Two</div>
                <div>Details Line Three</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Sample Image" />
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div>Details Line One</div>
                <div>Details Line Two</div>
                <div>Details Line Three</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Sample Image" />
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div>Details Line One</div>
                <div>Details Line Two</div>
                <div>Details Line Three</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="Sample Image" />
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div>Details Line One</div>
                <div>Details Line Two</div>
                <div>Details Line Three</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/QGb5Y/ this is what you meant?

Comment: @ilmk No, not quite. I want the sequence to go down the page one after the other, from top to bottom. The example to which you linked is going left to right, then top to bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, think I just worked it out. Should have tried for another 10 minutes before posting my question on Stack Overflow.

Solution was to use the following css style.

```
<style>
    .item {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .sidebar { 
        float: left; 
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add css like this:

```
.item {
    float: left;
}

.details {
    float: right;
}
.container {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
```

2nd Option is :

```
.sidebar, .details { 
    float: left; 
 }
.item{
    float: left;
    width:100%;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work exactly as I want: That gives me the elements going in an inline-esque sequence from left to right. I actually want them to track down the page.

Comment: Then you have to give `width` to the `.main` class and `.item` class

Comment: I'll consider it as a fallback position. I'd like to avoid setting the width if possible. :)

I'll try implementing this and any other answers in the real-world application over the next couple of days, then come back and mark as the answer whichever one I actually wind up using.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, btw!

Answer (score 1):

It's Simple, just try this out. It will allow you flexibility to add any Size of image or any amount of text. Layout will not break.

Add this CSS Code Only:

```
<style>
    .item{
        clear:both;
    }
    .sidebar, .details { 
        float: left; 
        padding-bottom:20px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you you use position absolute you can place things right where you want them.  With px, em or %.

Comment: Not all the information is known ahead of time, the content I'm dealing with in the actual application is dynamically generated from the database - lists within lists within lists. I've run into trouble in the past using absolute positioning in that scenario. Trying to keep things flexible.

Comment: I recently had the same problem due to an unclosed form and div. Closed the form and div fixed the problem.